# How to get data from array with exact match on populated field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

1.First I'm getting training ID from req.params

2.Next I'm using finById to get training details with ID's of groups that are participating in training

3.Next I'm getting group details and populating players model with selected fields.

3.1. Field attendance is array which contains player status and ID of training.

What i want is to get only data from attendance array where attendance.training.id = req.params but i get all attandence array. It's seems that my match doesn't work correctly.

Now i'm geting all data and filter it with foreach function on the server and then send filtered data to client, but thats not a deal. I want to get filtered data from DB

This is function i did

```
const { trainingId } = req.params;
  const training = await Training.findById(trainingId);
  const status = Player.schema.path('attendance.status').enumValues;
  const groups = await Group.find({ _id: { $in: training.group } }).populate({
    path: 'players',
    select: '_id name surName attendance',
    match: { 'attendance.training': trainingId }
  });
```

Group model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    coachName: { type: String, required: true },
    coachId: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: [true, 'Group must belong to at least one coach'],
        ref: 'User'
      }
    ]
    // Other fields for the group
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);
groupSchema.virtual('trainings', {
  ref: 'Training',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'group'
});

groupSchema.virtual('players', {
  ref: 'Player',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'group'
});

const Group = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);

module.exports = Group;
```

Training model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const trainingSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    startDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    endDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    description: String,
    group: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Group',
        required: [true, 'Trening must belong to a group']
      }
    ]

    // Inne pola dla treningu
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

const Training = mongoose.model('Training', trainingSchema);

module.exports = Training;
```

Player model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//const { Schema, model } = mongoose;

const playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      require: [true, 'A user must have a name'],
      trim: true
    },
    surName: {
      type: String,
      require: [true, 'A user must have a surname'],
      trim: true
    },
    dateOfBirth: {
      type: Date,
      require: [true, 'A user must have a date of Birth']
    },
    address: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    parentPhone: {
      type: Number,
      validate: {
        validator: function(val) {
          return val.toString().length === 9;
        },
        message: val => `${val.value} has to be 9 digits`
      }
    },
    pesel: {
      type: Number,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        validator: function(val) {
          return val.toString().length === 11;
        },
        message: val => `${val.value} has to be 11 digits`
      }
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: '/images/default-avatar.jpg'
    },
    attendance: [
      {
        training: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Training' },
        status: {
          type: String,
          enum: [
            'nieobecny',
            'obecny',
            'zwolniony',
            'usprawiedliwiony',
            'kontuzjowany',
            'na obozie'
          ],
          default: 'nieobecny'
        }
      }
    ],
    parentId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    group: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Group',
      default: '64b7e70fe2d0cc4715b59fa2'
    }
    // Inne pola dla zawodnika
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

const Player = mongoose.model('Player', playerSchema);

module.exports = Player;
```